# Configuration file windows backslash parse error

Tags: java, log4j2

I'm executing a JUnit-test where the tested class uses log4j2.1.
The configuration file `log4j2.xml` is accessible within the classpath.

When looking for configuration files, log4j finds the mentioned file at the location `C:\Users\...\build\resources\test\log4j2.xml` using `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory#getInputFromResource` (I shortened the full path for this post with the three dots). However, the URI class (`com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.URI`) cannot parse this input since it does not accept backslashes and thus fails at index 2 of the string. 
Specifically, log4j fails with the message

```
ERROR StatusLogger Error parsing C:\Users\...\build\resources\test\log4j2.xml com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.URI$MalformedURIException: Opaque part contains invalid character: \
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.URI.initializePath(URI.java:1142)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.URI.initialize(URI.java:582)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.URI.<init>(URI.java:335)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.URI.<init>(URI.java:298)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.expandSystemIdStrictOff1(XMLEntityManager.java:2207)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.expandSystemId(XMLEntityManager.java:2039)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.resolveEntityAsPerStax(XMLEntityManager.java:959)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1154)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1050)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:964)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:348)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfiguration.<init>(XmlConfiguration.java:137)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(XmlConfigurationFactory.java:44)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:472)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:442)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:254)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:419)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:138)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:147)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:41)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:175)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:426)
at se.studieren.brewberry.server.http.FaviconDelivery.<clinit>(FaviconDelivery.java:16)
at se.studieren.brewberry.server.http.FaviconDeliveryTest.setUp(FaviconDeliveryTest.java:37)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at mockit.integration.junit4.internal.JUnit4TestRunnerDecorator.invokeExplosively(JUnit4TestRunnerDecorator.java:50)
at mockit.integration.junit4.internal.MockFrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(MockFrameworkMethod.java:40)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:69)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:48)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:105)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:355)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
ERROR StatusLogger No logging configuration
```

when it tries to initialize the log-system for the first time for the status logger.

The system is run on Windows 8.1 with Java 8 and the test is executed using the IntelliJ14 gradle wrapper.

Is this a bug in log4j2.1? Is there any way to get around this on Windows without changing the log4j implementation?

Comment: Are you sure that the error is while parsing the file location and not the log4j2.xml? I mean the log4j2.xml does not contain this character right? Even with log4j v1, log4j library was able to parse the log4j.xml file present in the classpath by converting '\' to '/' automatically.

Comment: Yes, debugging the program showed that the URI rejects the file path.

Comment: Can you show the full stack trace? I'm interested to know where in `getInputFromResource` things go wrong...

Comment: Is the log4j2 config file location specified with the `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=path/to/config` system property? I find it strange that the path has three dots in it...

Comment: The three dots are just a replacement of mine, it's actually the full path to the configuration file in the file system. 
I added the full stack trace to the initial post.

Comment: The log4j config file location is not specified via `-Dlog4j.configurationFile` since it is placed within the classpath.